# Error: ENOENT util.rb No such file or directory after upgrading to compass 1.0.1/sass 3.4.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass

Here's everything the terminal spits back, with --trace-

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["670"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/util.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/aristidesstaffieri/sass
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/util.rb:670:in `realpath'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/util.rb:670:in `realpath'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:16:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/engine.rb:192:in `new'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/engine.rb:192:in `block in normalize_options'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/engine.rb:190:in `map'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/engine.rb:190:in `normalize_options'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:52:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:203:in `new'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:203:in `update_stylesheets'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:294:in `watch'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:46:in `watch!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:41:in `perform'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

This only started happening after I updated, and all of my gems are updated. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing compass/sass. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related to: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1406.  If a previous version worked, the logical course of action would be to roll back to the previous version and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem you were having is the new update of the gem. With this modification you get back to the previous version.

I modified Gemfile. I added this line **gem 'compass','0.12.6'**

**This is my first lines at Gemfile**

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    ruby '1.9.3'

    gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.15'

    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails'
      gem 'compass-rails'
      gem 'compass','0.12.6'
      gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
      gem 'uglifier'
    end
```

I think this is what you wanted, but if not, let me know as many times as you need.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Sass ([3.4.3](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html)) as of September 4th seems to fix this issue (confirmed with Ruby 2.0.0 and Compass 1.0.1).

You could try running `gem update sass` and see if it solves your problem.